# Counting vanishing conditions for a section of a line bundle

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry

I am reading Lazarsfeld's positivity 1 and there is a passage I'm not able to understand... In proposition 1.1.31 he determines the number of conditions for the vanishing to order $c$ of a global section $s$ of a line bundle on an $n$ dimensional variety as

$$\binom{n+c-1}{n}$$

Now, as far as I know this is the number of compositions of $n$ as sum of $c$ nonnegative integers. But why is this the total number of conditions
$$\frac{\partial^k s}{\partial x_{1}^{a_1}...\partial x_{n}^{a_n}}=0$$
for $k=0,...,c-1$?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the case of curves ($n=1$) first. So you have a line bundle $L$ on a curve $X$, and you want to know how many conditions describe the vanishing of $s,s',\dots s^{(c-1)}$ for a section $s\in H^0(X,L)$. The notion of derivative of a section of a line bundle is formulated in terms of *jet bundles*. If I am not misunderstanding your question, what you want is simply $$\textrm{the rank of the jet bundle }J^{c-1}L.$$ On a curve it is easy to see that $$\textrm{rank }J^{c-1}L=c.$$ Indeed, a section $s$ is represented on a local chart by a regular function $f$ on the curve, and the corresponding section $D^{c-1}s\in H^0(X,J^{c-1}L)$ is represented on that chart by the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
f\\
f'\\
\vdots\\
f^{(c-1)}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
So you see that there are $c=\binom{1+c-1}{1}$ vanishing conditions, as wanted.

For $n>1$, the "vanishing" becomes the vanishing of some minors. The number you are after is the number of minors that are supposed to vanish. For instance, for $n=2$ and local coordinates $x_1,x_2$, you want to describe the condition $$\begin{pmatrix}
f\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial^{c-1} f}{\partial x_1}
\end{pmatrix}\wedge \begin{pmatrix}
f\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial^{c-1} f}{\partial x_2}
\end{pmatrix}=0.$$
There are $\binom{c}{2}=\binom{2+c-1}{2}$ vanishing conditions here, as wanted.

I leave it to you to generalize the above for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about these jet bundles. What I was thinking is that since locally a section is a polynomial $P$ (or at least we can consider it as such for the purposes of vanishing) then this is equivalent to count the number of conditions for the vanishing of all the derivatives of order $c-1$ of the homogenization of $P$.